# How can I find the Nth most common value in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the one below:

```
$array = Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5 ,5, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

I know I can easily find the most repeated value in this array with a procedure like that one:

```
$array = Array(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3);
$counts = array_count_values($array);
arsort($counts);

echo key($counts);
```

But how can I find the **second** most repeated value? Or the **third**? Or the **fourth** and beyond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short your question boils down to: how to get the *nth* key from an array?

Like this:

```
echo array_keys($counts)[1];
```

For ancient PHP versions which don't support this syntax:

```
$keys = array_keys($counts);
echo $keys[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

By sorting and displaying the whole array you can get them in order:

```
$array = Array(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3);
$counts = array_count_values($array);
arsort($counts);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($counts);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

Each subsequent element in the array would have the values as keys in descending order of their appearance in the array.

Comment: I tried this approach but `$counts[0]` is giving me undefined offset error.

Comment: My bad @Maximus2012, I was typing without coffee :)